# Grouping dates by Periods in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, data.table, aggregate

I a have a table:

```
   Date     Value1   Value2   ...
09/01/2008        
10/01/2008
11/01/2008
12/01/2008
01/01/2009
02/01/2009
03/01/2008
04/01/2009
05/01/2009
06/01/2009
07/01/2009
08/01/2008
```

I need to group dates next way: 09/01/2008 10/01/2008 11/01/2008 make equal to "2008" and the rest dates make equal to "2008.2009"

Is it possible to do something like that:

```
Date[Date>=09/01/2008 & Date<=11/01/2008] <- 2008
Date[Date>=12/01/2008 & Date<=08/01/2009] <- 2008.2009
```

The output should be in the following format :

```
Date        Value1   Value2  ...
2008        
2008
2008
2008.2009
2008.2009
2008.2009
2008.2009
2008.2009
2008.2009
2008.2009
2008.2009
2008.2009
```

Thank you!

Comment: In order to do ranges you need either to convert to real Date-classed vectors or to rearrange the dates so that the year values appear first in a YYYY/MM/DD format. Furthermore you have two values: 03/01/2008 and 08/01/2008 that are not in agreement with your definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dat <-read.table(text="Date  
09/01/2008        
10/01/2008
11/01/2008
12/01/2008
01/01/2009
02/01/2009
03/01/2009
04/01/2009
05/01/2009
06/01/2009
07/01/2009
08/01/2009",head=T)

dat$dt <- with( dat, as.Date(Date,format="%m/%d/%Y"))

with(dat, c("2008", "2008.2009", "NA")[ findInterval( dt,
                                            c( as.Date("2008/09/01") , 
                                               as.Date("2008/11/02") , 
                                               as.Date("2009/08/02") )
                                                    )
                                       ] )

# [1] "2008"      "2008"      "2008"      "2008.2009" "2008.2009" "2008.2009"
# [7] "2008.2009" "2008.2009" "2008.2009" "2008.2009" "2008.2009" "2008.2009"
```

You need to advance some of the dates by 1 day so that `findInterval` can abide by your somewhat irregular use of ">=" and "<="

Answer (score 2):

If the dates in your dataset range only from 2008/09/01 to 2009/08/01 and only requires of 2 year-groups, you could try to do below using `data.table`.

```
# Use @BondedDust toy data
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)  # convert to data table
dat[, new_col := ifelse(dt %between% c("2008-09-01", "2008-11-01"),
                        "2008", "2008.2009")]
dat

# you get
          Date         dt   new_col
 1: 09/01/2008 2008-09-01      2008
 2: 10/01/2008 2008-10-01      2008
 3: 11/01/2008 2008-11-01      2008
 4: 12/01/2008 2008-12-01 2008.2009
 5: 01/01/2009 2009-01-01 2008.2009
 6: 02/01/2009 2009-02-01 2008.2009
 7: 03/01/2009 2009-03-01 2008.2009
 8: 04/01/2009 2009-04-01 2008.2009
 9: 05/01/2009 2009-05-01 2008.2009
10: 06/01/2009 2009-06-01 2008.2009
11: 07/01/2009 2009-07-01 2008.2009
12: 08/01/2009 2009-08-01 2008.2009
```

Comment: Right. I started out with that approach in mind and even had the code written, but went for the `findInterval` method because it generalizes better.